# ElasticSearch SearchParseException : Parse Failure [Failed to parse source] when using geo_distance filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am new to ElasticSeach and i have indexed a list of cities in the elasticseach cluster. Each city containing the details like city, state, location (lat and long) etc.

Now my requirement is to search for the cities within 20km range of a particular location, for which i am passing the lat and long for a particular city which is already indexed into the cluster.

Here is my indexed data as show in UI of head plugin of elasticsearch:

```
{
    "_index": "us_large_cities",
    "_type": "city",
    "_id": "AVqDpwkjfjWoT7yVe_qt",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "city": "Lincoln",
        "state": "NE",
        "location": {
            "lat": "40.8000011",
            "lon": "-96.6669599"
         }
     }
}
```

and here is my curl command for searching out the data:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/us_large_cities/city/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "20km",
                "location" : {
                    "lat" : 40.8000011,
                    "lon" : -96.6669599
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}'
```

And i got the SearchParseException and here is the complete stack trace:

```
org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [us_large_cities][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
{
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "20km",
                "location" : {
                    "lat" : 40.8000011,
                    "lon" : -96.6669599
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:687)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:543)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:515)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:277)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:231)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:228)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:559)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [us_large_cities] failed to find geo_point field [location]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.GeoDistanceFilterParser.parse(GeoDistanceFilterParser.java:159)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.executeFilterParser(QueryParseContext.java:347)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerFilter(QueryParseContext.java:328)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.FilteredQueryParser.parse(FilteredQueryParser.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:281)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.innerParse(IndexQueryParserService.java:382)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:281)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:276)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryParseElement.parse(QueryParseElement.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:671)
    ... 9 more
```

I have searched out various posts as possted in SO, but none worked for me well.
Any suggestions, where i am making mistake?

Comment: Which elastic version are you using?

Comment: Its 1.4.4 version

Answer (score 0):

```
[us_large_cities] failed to find geo_point field [location]
```

This is your error, since if you want to use the `geo_distance` filter, you have to index the location field as a `geo_point` field. More info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-geo-point-type.html).

Edit: so

```
"location": {
            "lat": "40.8000011",
            "lon": "-96.6669599"
         }
```

needs to be defined as:

```
{
    "city_location" : {
        "location" : {
            "lat" : 41.12,
            "lon" : -71.34
        }
    }
}
```